# When Installing Meteor, Getting Stuck on Password

Tags: macos, terminal, meteor

After I enter the install line for Meteor:

```
$ curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

I get the following:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4506    0  4506    0     0   7779      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7782
Removing your existing Meteor installation.
Downloading Meteor distribution
######################################################################## 100.0%

Meteor 0.9.0.1 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
Writing a launcher script to /usr/local/bin/meteor for your convenience.
This may prompt for your password.

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:[ ]
```

But then it doesn't even let me type anything in! Plus I only assume it means my user password on Mac OSX? Maybe some setting wrong somewhere on my machine? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` simply doesn't echo your password. Unlike many GUI tools, you won't get `***` or `•••` either, but it is recording what you type. Just type in your password and finish with Enter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the thing is, it won't let me type any characters with my keyboard at that point! That's the really troubling thing.

Comment: Well, what I'm saying is that it's probably recording what you're typing, only that you're not seeing it, since it doesn't show anything.